# Add-AzureVhd ResourceNotFound: The storage account was not found

Tags: azure-active-directory

I need to send a vhd file via PS, and I've tried a few variations but I believe this is the easier to troubleshoot:

`PS C:\Users\Poly> Add-AzureVhd -destination https://onlystorage2134.blob.core.windows.net/rprm/rprm-10.9.0_80-253372-azure.vhd -localfilepath D:\Downloads\plcm-rpp-rprm-10.9.0_80-253372-azure.vhd`

`Add-AzureVhd : ResourceNotFound: The storage account 'onlystorage2134' was not found. At line:1 char:1`

I've confirmed the storage exists:

`PS C:\Users\Poly> Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object { $_.StorageAccountName -eq $storageAccountName }`

```
ResourceGroupName      : Only_Group
StorageAccountName     : onlystorage2134
Id                     : /subscriptions/b6392287-908e-4d6f-8f45-c97772dd2844/resourceGroupsOnly_Group/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/onlystorage2134
Location               : eastus
Sku                    : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Sku
Kind                   : StorageV2
Encryption             : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Encryption
AccessTier             : Hot
CreationTime           : 11/23/2021 4:03:40 PM
CustomDomain           : 
Identity               : 
LastGeoFailoverTime    : 
PrimaryEndpoints       : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Endpoints
PrimaryLocation        : eastus
ProvisioningState      : Succeeded
SecondaryEndpoints     : 
SecondaryLocation      : 
StatusOfPrimary        : Available
StatusOfSecondary      : 
Tags                   : {}
EnableHttpsTrafficOnly : False
NetworkRuleSet         : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.Models.PSNetworkRuleSet
Context                : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.LazyAzureStorageContext
ExtendedProperties     : {}
```

I've also confirmed all of the possible IAM roles I could possibly find in the documentation. Can anyone help me send the correct reference or tell me if I need anything special in the setup of the storage container?

Comment: You forget to enclose your destination and localfilepath with " " .Try with this Script : Add-AzureVhd -Destination "https://onlystorage2134.blob.core.windows.net/rprm/rprm-10.9.0_80-253372-azure.vhd" -LocalFilePath "D:\Downloads\plcm-rpp-rprm-10.9.0_80-253372-azure.vhd"

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using old Azure PowerShell Module instead of New [`Az Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-6.6.0). I tested using both the modules and using the old one I am getting the same error that you are receiving as shown below:

[image]

As a Solution, I used the `Az Module` and ran [`Add-AzVHD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/add-azvhd?view=azps-6.6.0) command instead of `Add-AzureVHD` . The command will be like below:

```
Add-AzVhd -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroupname_where_storage_account_exists" -Destination "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/blobname.vhd" -LocalFilePath "path_for_vhd_file"
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

The Storage Account to be used *should not* have `Hierarchical Namespace Enabled` i.e. it should be ***General account not a ADLS account.***

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I had to install the latest PowerShell (7.2.0) as well as install the module with Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force -AllowClobber

Comment: Glad to be of help @ianrego :)